# How to show the relation with Frobenius problem and Shell Sort?

Tags: sorting, time-complexity, shellsort

According to the Wikipedia [page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shellsort#Computational_complexity),

> Every h-sorted and k-sorted array is also (ah + bk)-sorted, for any non negative integers a and b

How is this possible? I have seen another [question](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/47096/why-does-decreasing-the-gap-size-in-shell-sort-never-undo-previous-sorts) that explains why an h-sorted array remains h-sorted after k-sort, where k is smaller than h, but it does not address this problem.